# Building pygpu succeeded but import pygpu fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, theano, ubuntu-16.04

My theano/pygpu seems is broken. I build libgpuarray / pygpu from repo from a python 3 virtual env [as mentionned](http://deeplearning.net/software/libgpuarray/installation.html) as a user:

```
~$ DEVICE="cuda0" python -c "import pygpu;pygpu.test()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jeanpat/VirtualEnv/venv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pygpu-0.6.5-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/pygpu/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import gpuarray, elemwise, reduction
ImportError: libgpuarray.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

(venv3) jeanpat@laptop:~$ DEVICE="cuda0" python -c "import theano"
ERROR (theano.gpuarray): pygpu was configured but could not be imported or is too old (version 0.6 or higher required)
NoneType
```

Trying to upgrade theano didn't fix the problem. It seems that there's an old pygpu somewhere as the error message on import theano shows.

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem on Windows 10 and the error message was completely backwards - you need to downgrade!  I had the latest pygpu: v0.6.4.   However, when I downgraded pygpu to v0.6.2 then Theano used the GPU!

Run the following command to downgrade:

```
    conda install theano pygpu=0.6.2
```

I hope that helps

Robert

Comment: How I can configure it using the virtual environment (without anconda)?